# Riding motorcycles in Medellin, Colombia with a US DL

Tags: driving-licenses, motorcycles, colombia

I'm planning to visit Medellin and Bogota sometime in the near future. I've a U.S. DL which endorses motorcycles. Is it legal to ride motorcycles in Colombia with a US driver's license? Is it required to carry any other identification other than the U.S. DL in case if I'm on the road?

Comment: The International Driver Permit is always a good idea, whether it's required or not.

Comment: If you're not a Colombian resident, as you appear not to be, you should perhaps be carrying your passport with you while you are in Colombia.

Answer (score 1):

The [national law](http://www.colombia.com/noticias/codigotransito/t2c2.asp) allows to ride with your foreign license. However you should issue an [International Driver Permit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Driving_Permit). Don't expect the local police to be able to read or understand your USA license, the translation provided by the IDP should do the work.